# What is the appropriate salutation for non-technical university staff in India?

Tags: etiquette, email, india

There are issues in my living quarters provided by my university and I need to write a letter to the responding authority. The authority is a non-teaching staff.

As a research scholar, how should I salute them while sending an email or a letter.

I am confused between "Respected sir" and "Hello sir". Which one is appropriate among the both and is there any appropriate one other than these?

Comment: @hanugm Please edit responses to comments into your post rather than replying as a comment. Comments aren't meant to last and people might read your post without seeing the comments. The answer would be totally different in another place. In the US for example both of the options you gave would sound silly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *Dear Sir*.
I know students and research scholars use *Respected Sir* in case they address professors but *Dear Sir* will work in all cases.

Using *Hello* or *Hi* in a formal letter is frowned upon in an Indian university.

Comment: "_Dear Sir will work in all cases_"  What if the university staff is a woman?

Comment: If you don't know which staff member you are addressing, it is better to say "Dear Sir/Madam". In fact, most letters in India are addressed this way. The problem is the letter is copied to many people and sometimes it becomes difficult to determine who the author is addressing.